# Equal rights for Lesbian or Gay couples without "redefining" marriage

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, marriage, same-sex-marriage

What is the mindset of the people who support equal civil rights for homosexuals but disagree with Obergefell v. Hodges because it redefines the word "marriage", which they believe is a sacred thing between a man and a woman?

**EDIT:**  Maybe the premise of my question is wrong.  Are there any people that really fall into the category described above?  It would be helpful to find at least one writer who does.

What kind of ruling do they think the supreme court should give in order to ensure that gays have equal civil rights?

Would they prefer that the supreme court ruled that all laws with the word "marriage" in them are unconstitutional, because marriage is between a man and a woman, and therefore laws with the word "marriage" don't grant equal protection to Lesbian or Gay couples?  That would eliminate a lot of laws overnight, and potentially have a lot of unintended consequences, so it's hard to imagine someone who is overall expressing conservative opinions to want that.

I think such people probably exist.  For example, [Barack Obama supported equal rights for Lesbian and Gay couples, but had a conservative definition of marriage back in 2008](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/barackobama/3375059/Barack-Obama-marriage-is-between-a-man-and-a-woman.html), so probably some people still have the same two opinions.

Comment: I think you're confusing two concepts. On one hand, we have a view on jurisprudence which would dictate how the supreme court should rule based on the law in the constitution. On the other hand we have what they think the law should ideally be. Which is your question about? One's views on homosexuality aren't really relevant to how one thinks the law is written.

Comment: I think it's typically a convoluted idea of religion vs. law. Both use the term 'marriage' which bothers some people. But technically, the law doesn't dictate the term's definition within a religious context.

Comment: I edited the question to put more of an emphasis on finding actual people who hold the views described in the first paragraph.   I think if we can find one or two writers who have that view, assuming they are intelligent and thoughtful, they will probably explain what kind of ruling the supreme court should have given in their world.

Comment: @lazarusL: Yeah, I'm asking if a specific category of people exists, and if they do, what kind of ruling they would want the supreme court to give.  So it's more about that and less about describing the ideal state of the laws.

Comment: I think that type of person, though, is upset about the redefinition of a term in the context outside of the law--which the court isn't doing. So it's more of a punditry stance than a legal one.

Comment: I believe this *type of person* exists, since I'm one of them :)

Comment: @DavidGrayson many (I'd like to hope almost all) people think that the supreme court should make decisions based on the law as it is, not in order to promote a specific agenda. So people in this group shouldn't have a common view on what they think the supreme court should do.

Comment: @Bregalad seems like you're the person that needs to answer the question!

Comment: @Bregalad I wasn't the one asking, so not sure what I'd want  you to say. But it does sound like your 'mindset' is one that values the definition of the word 'marriage' outside of the law. That makes sense (even if I don't agree with it). I think that's a valid answer to the question.

Comment: @DA, ok I turned my comment into an answer, although it's the first time on PO I have to give my personal political opinion as an "answer" so I'm a bit worried it's inadequate.

Comment: @Bregalad I think this is one of those cases where your opinion is actually a fact that answers the question. (It's a fact that you have an opinion on the topic that matches the POV the question is looking for) So it actually makes sense a an answer (at least it makes sense to me!) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** *This post only words my own opinion, and I ignore if it is representative of other people holding the same position.*

I would support no discrimination against homosexual people and would ensure they are not excluded from the society. They already run into much risk of being discriminated against by individuals, it should not be the state's role to discriminate even more against them, instead it should give what it can to protect them against all kinds of discrimination.

I not would support changing the definition of traditional marriage any bit as marriage is a **very long lived** tradition that should be kept, and involve a man and a woman in most cultures. (Although some cultures allows some men to have multiple wives, but in the countries with such cultures same-sex marriage is usually out of question yet).

I would support civil unions only for same sex couples, and marriage only for regular couples. That's also a good thing because it's exactly what my country does, and I believe it's the right thing - two different kind of couples, two different kinds of unions.

As a matter of comparison, to solve the problem of "black" people discriminated by against "white" persons, we don't paint black people in white, instead, we forbid to give hate speech and discriminations against black. A similar approach should be taken for same-sex couples.

Comment: This was my original opinion on the matter, but someone pointed out to me that unless legislation is passed which makes "civil unions" equivalent to "marriage" for all legal purposes (taxes, next-of-kin, health benefits, etc) then this solution doesn't solve most of the issues that triggered the desire for same-sex marriage in the first place.  *With* said legislation, this would be a good solution, but then it raises the question of why not have everything be a civil union?

Comment: I belive it could make sense if Churches allows to marry (regular straight) couples who just made a civil union, it would make sense. *Civil union* would be a purely civil term and *marriage* a purely religious one, and it would not ruin the long lived tradition of marriage. I do not know if such a shift is desirable, though. This is a complicated debate.

Comment: Thanks for the opinions.  I am not sure if it could actually be written as a supreme court ruling that would have any effect,  but maybe that's just because I'm ignorant of what kind of rulings a supreme court could give.

Comment: @Bregalad - Yep.  That would make perfect sense.  And many people do say it probably should have gone that way.  It's *definitely* complicated.

Comment: @DavidGrayson that goes back to it being more of a pundit-based argument than one that actually has legal merit. The reasons to not allow gay marriage tend to fall into religious and language based arguments, neither of which really have much bearing on the legal definition.

Comment: @DA The same could be said in the other direction, the only argument to allow "gay" marriage is very recent gay-pride propaganda.

Comment: @Bregalad people can say anything. :) But I don't think the same logic is there. BTW, I think this is an interesting topic and am all for discussing in chat if interested. But here, I think you answered the question well and I don't think we need to clutter the comments. @ me in chat if you'd like, though!

Comment: I agree completely, gay couples are regular couples

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with children. Marriage was first a bond to ensure that couple would stay together to raise children. With the state growing, more laws were added to the term marriage. Now there is a conflict where people still believe children need a mother and father to raise children (traditional marriage) but don't want to prevent same sex couple to have all these important government benefit (civil union).

Comment: Any sources for marriage first being a bond to raise children?

Comment: Lots of marriages don't involve children, and same-sex couples can have (or adopt) and raise children.

Comment: One judge rejected this argument by noting that he had officiated at a wedding between a couple in their 80's.  If marriage is about kids, should heterosexual couples of such an advanced age be allowed to marry? What about younger heterosexual couples who are unable to reproduce for medical reasons?

Comment: I'm not talking about today, but the traditional meaning of marriage in the past. Marriage comes from matrimonium which is "mother+obligation". Culturally (at least western), in the past, sexual relationship was done after marriage to prevent the woman to have children (or else the family would have to provide). What I'm saying is that marriage today is very different with all the legal law attached to it but the attachment to the historical meaning of the word is still there.

Comment: The Catholic Church (which I understand is an important source of western marriage tradition) includes the word "children" in their vows. The explanation I've heard included the possibility of children very late in life and cited a biblical example.

Comment: This is, of course, a common argument, but incredibly flawed given that nearly half of parents are divorced.

Comment: @blip There's a difference between talking about an ideal and the reality of marriage. Also, we have to look at the divorce rate of first marriage, those that are actively religious or not and those that have children together. People that have kids and are active in their religion usually have the community to help them stay together for the kids.

Comment: @the_lotus that is all true. It is a common argument, for sure.

Comment: There are plenty of heterosexual couples who cannot have kids, or who don't want kids. And there are plenty of homosexual couples who are raising children. Or have children, like Paul Burrall whose two adult sons joined him at his wedding to another man. And are you saying that folks over fifty shouldn't marry?

Comment: @the_lotus: "Divorce is not the death of a marriage. It's the funeral". Peer pressure can lead to a marriage not getting divorced. It doesn't lead to a meaningful marriage. Many couples stay married until the kids have grown up. What kind of marriage is that?

Comment: @gnasher729 wow, this is such a sensitive subject. I never say they shouldn't mary, I never they can't have kids, I never say it was good to stay together when the marriage is bad... I'm talking about the ideal of marriage. Why some people don't want to redefine marriage and what marriage is to them.

Answer (score -1):

In many animal species, including the human animal, there is a very strong tendency for females to form exclusive lifetime mating relationships with males(*).  Such mating relationships have formed a key cornerstone of almost every human society, and have done so long before the development of government, religion, or anything resembling modern language.  In English, the term "marriage" is used to refer to such relationships among humans.

(*) In many human and animal societies, the exclusivity is reciprocal, forming mating pairs; occasionally, multiple females may mate with the same male but with no one else.

Those who would repurpose the term marriage seek to erase the distinction between a kind of relationship which has existed since time immemorial and has been recognized by practically every human society throughout history, and other forms of relationship of much more recent invention.

If government were to pass a law saying that the term "red" shall be used to refer to colors whose peak wavelength is 500-550nm, that might compel states to start painting stop signs green, but it wouldn't make grass red.

Likewise if the state declares that groups of individuals which do not comprise exactly one male and at least one female may call themselves "married", that may affect the way in which various laws apply to those people, but it wouldn't mean they had the same kind of relationship the term "marriage" was coined to represent.

Comment: I'm not sure this directly addresses the question, as it still uses the term 'marriage' in our final example.

Comment: @blip: The question asked about the mindset of people who maintain that marriage necessarily involve relationships between men and women, but do not oppose extending many to people in some other kinds of relationships the benefits afforded to married couples.  I am such a person; I believe I have explained my mindset.  Does my second-to-last paragraph not make the meaning of my last paragraph clear?  There are a number of situations where statutes define words in a fashion contrary to their common-language meaning; in some cases, adjectives are coined to disambiguate such usage.  For example,

Comment: ...one might in some contexts refer to the new stop-sign color as "statutory red" to distinguish it from the color of ripe tomatoes.  I'm not sure what terminology would become most prevalent to distinguish the "marriages" which are invented by government from those of the form which predates government, but I think a distinction should still be drawn.

Comment: Well, I'm unclear as to whether you believe the term 'marriage' should be stricken from laws, or kept--which I think is what the original question was going for.

Comment: @blip: I believe that the term "marriage" should be used in places where it is applicable (with its thousands-of-years-old meaning), and that other terms should be used when the term "marriage" is not applicable.

Comment: OK, so I think it sounds like you are saying in legal context, a new term should be used and the term 'marriage' be left outside of the legal realm?

Comment: @blip: I believe that the term "marriage" should be kept in the legal realm in places where its meaning is applicable, and replaced by, or used in conjunction with, other more appropriate terms in places where some other meaning would be more appropriate (e.g. for tax status, "Married or civilly joined").  Some usages should presumably stay as they are; trying, for example, to apply to a lesbian couple a statute specifying that a husband is to be regarded as the presumed father of his wife's children would yield nonsensical results.

Comment: I see what you are getting at. The catch is, of course, is that there is no one defined definition for 'marriage' inside or outside of the legal context. I do understand the argument, though.